# PDF content & SEO

Tags: pdf, seo

my client has this "PDF based" website. It basically has no content because every article has a PDF attached presented to users via Google Docs Embed.
So bottom line, Google has pretty much nothing to index here and therefore his website doesn't rank that well on search engines.

So my question is - I know hidden content is somewhat acceptable by Google if it's relative to other content on the website. So my idea would be to extract the content from the PDFs via PHP and display it hidden on the website. But how can Google know if it's relative if there's literally no other content there (except for the anchor links in the navigation)

So I need the content hidden because it's pointless from users perspective to have the same content presented multiple times.
And there has to be some content there because the PDFs are embeded via Google Doc Viewer and Google can't see it's content. Further more, client does this because he doesn't want Google to reach his PDFs... But he wants Google to reach it's content...

I know this is somewhat unreasonable but the client wants what he wants and I just want to check if anybody has any idea how to solve this issue?
Would it be ok to just display the hidden content extracted from the PDF on the page where the PDF is embeded via Google Docs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the content there solely for Google's benefit will get you into trouble as that is *exactly* what Google doesn't want you to do. Serving up content just to manipulate your rankings is the biggest no-no in the book.

If you have the content already in text form, why not display it that way instead of as PDF documents? This way your site is easier to use, search engine friendly, and doesn't require the flaw-ridden Adobe Acrobat to be used? If you still want the document to be available in PDF just make it available for download.